# Bash:check arguments passed on 'while-case' loop

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments

I have this bash code:

```
usages() {
    echo "$0 --user= --pass= --serverName= --dbList="
    exit 1
}
while [[ "$1" != "" ]] && [[ ."$1" = .--* ]]; do
case $1 in
    "--user="* )
        DB_USER="${1#*=}"
        shift ;;
    "--pass="* )
        DB_PASS="${1#*=}"
        shift ;;
    "--dbList="* )
        DB_NAME="${1#*=}"
        shift ;;
    "--serverName="* )
        SERVER_NAME="${1#*=}"
        shift ;;
    --help )
        usages ;;
    * )
        usages ;;
esac
done
```

Let say the script name is `test.sh`
when I run test.sh like this:

```
./test.sh --user=user1 --pass=pass1 --serverName=testing
```

The script still running. The problem is i need a arguments checker and it should check 4 parameter and arguments are presented. If not equal to 4 params it should run 'usages' function.
Kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: You can use $# or getopts to test the number of parameters being passed.

Comment: seems cant solved with $#. Can you provide me the examples with getopts? @RamanSailopal

Comment: Sorry it seems different case @Lukasz_Plawny

Comment: Checking ./test.sh --user=user1 --pass=pass1 --serverName=testing against $# returns 3 against ./test.sh --user=user1 --pass=pass1 --serverName=testing --dblist="aaa bbb ccc ddd" returns 4?